# How to set menu in magento2

Tags: magento2, menu

**Top navigation menu not displaying in my Magento.** I refreshed cache and made reindexing.

I followed many links and made all the possible options provided from the links. Still, it's not showing the menu.

I just have a main menu with a submenu, in the **"All stores"** already have associated the menu, but even so, the menu is not displayed.

Comment: Is there any custom extension?

Answer (score 2):

**checklist**

Login to admin. In `Product -> Categories` click your category then check the below options are enable in General information tab

1. Is Active -> YES
2. Include in Navigation Menu -> YES

In Display Setting

1. Is Anchor -> YES

All the categories should comes under **default category**

[image]

Comment: i have  setting but no working the menu .not display in front end menu

Comment: same that but not display menu

Comment: check my updates. mostly you made mistake in category creation so cross check.

Comment: it is happen suddenly or from the beginning itself ?

Comment: thank it's work fine.

Comment: glad! what is the problem?

Comment: i have not seen the menu under in default category

Comment: how to set page in menu

Comment: what I can't get you? raised that new question don't mix up with this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if you were able to fix your issue, but this has fixed mine when it's been related to Varnish:

in default.xml

```
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="store.menu">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav.fix" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml" before="-"/>
    </referenceBlock>
```